# How to reattach or move a ttk.Treeview item back to its original location?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The following sample script allows the detachment of root item(s) of a `ttk.Treeview` widget after the mouse button 1 is released after clicking it and reattaches the detached items when the `ttk.Button` widget is released. However, I achieved the reattachments via manipulating the item's text which I find cumbersome and not always possible in situations where its text does not contain any indexing.

Quoting the documentation of the `move`(or `reattach`) method of the `ttk.Treeview` widget

```
def move(self, item, parent, index):
    """Moves item to position index in parent's list of children.

    It is illegal to move an item under one of its descendants. If
    index is less than or equal to zero, item is moved to the
    beginning, if greater than or equal to the number of children,
    it is moved to the end. If item was detached it is reattached."""
    self.tk.call(self._w, "move", item, parent, index)
```

Specifically, `If item was detached it is reattached`.

Hence, is there a simpler way to reattach the detached item(s) back to their original index location without having to do what my script is currently doing?

**Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.detached_items = set()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.reinsert = ttk.Button(self.root, text= "Reinsert",
                                   command=self.reinsert_items)
        self.reinsert.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.detach_selection)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def detach_selection(self, event):
        selected_items = event.widget.selection()
        print(f"{selected_items=}")
        for item in selected_items:
            self.detached_items.add(item)
        event.widget.detach(*selected_items)

    def reinsert_items(self):
        for iid in self.detached_items.copy():
            print(f"{iid=}")
            text = self.tree.item(iid)["text"]
            print(f"{text=}")
            if self.tree.exists(iid):
                self.tree.move(iid, "", int(text[5:]))
                # self.tree.move(iid, "", "")  # "" as index don't work
            else:
                self.tree.move(iid, "", "end")
            self.detached_items.remove(iid)
        print(f"{self.detached_items=}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: If there is no change of the number of items in the treeview after detaching items, then you can insert back those items in reverse order.  However you need to save the index of the detached item as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @acw1668.

I have set up `self.items_index` as a reference to the `dict` object to store the index of each item as it is being detached. Thereafter, this `dict` object is accessed in a reverse order to acquire the corresponding item index to reattach the items.

**Note:** This method of using a `dict` object is guaranteed to work for Python 3.7 and above as dictionary order is guaranteed to be according to the insertion order.

**Working script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items_index = {}  # Added
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.reinsert = ttk.Button(self.root, text= "Reinsert",
                                   command=self.reinsert_items)
        self.reinsert.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.detach_selection)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def detach_selection(self, event):
        print(f"\nDetach")
        selected_items = event.widget.selection()
        print(f"{selected_items=}")
        for item in selected_items:
            self.items_index[item] = self.tree.index(item)
            event.widget.detach(item)
        print(f"{self.items_index=}\n")

    def reinsert_items(self):
        print(f"\nReinsert")
        iids = list(self.items_index.keys())
        print(f"{iids=}")
        for iid in iids[::-1]:
            index = self.items_index[iid]
            self.tree.move(iid, "", index)
            del self.items_index[iid]
        print(f"{self.items_index=}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Comment: Your solution will insert some items back to wrong positions.

Comment: @acw1668 Yah.... I think I can't use set() to store the detached item,  reworking it...

Comment: @acw1668 I have corrected my script. It should work. I did not know you had submitted an answer. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the *current index* of the detached item as well and insert them back in reverse order of detach.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.detached_items = []   # use list instead
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.reinsert = ttk.Button(self.root, text= "Reinsert",
                                   command=self.reinsert_items)
        self.reinsert.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.detach_selection)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def detach_selection(self, event):
        selected_items = event.widget.selection()
        for item in selected_items:
            # save the index as well
            idx = event.widget.index(item)
            self.detached_items.append((item, idx))
            event.widget.detach(item)
        print(f"{self.detached_items=}")

    def reinsert_items(self):
        # insert back detached items in reverse order
        for iid, idx in self.detached_items[::-1]:
            print(f"{iid=}, {idx=}")
            self.tree.move(iid, "", idx)
        self.detached_items.clear()
        print(f"{self.detached_items=}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

*Suggest not to run `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`*

Comment: That is not working if you select few items at a time. That may be possible if you hold shift after you have detached any item. Or after you reinsert items, you can touch "heading", items will be deleted and then reinsert in a wrong order. I think you need to reverse the selected_items as well, like this: `for item in selected_items[::-1]`